# How can I change the order of dates in my table column?

Tags: reactjs, xlsx, sheetjs

Each row goes into the array correctly. There are dates between A13-A28 in my spreadsheet, but it may not always be between A13 and A28.  Can I sort them as I want?

I extracted the regex if there is only the date line in the column. Is there a more practical way to both filter and sort?

```js
  const [columns, setColumns] = useState([]);
   const handFile = async (e) => {
     const file = e.target.files[0];
     const fileReader = new FileReader()
     setFileName(file.name)
     const data = await file.arrayBuffer();
     const workbook = XLSX.readFile(data);
     const worksheet = workbook.Sheets[workbook.SheetNames[0]];
     const jsonData = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(worksheet, {
         header: 1,
         defval: "",
         blankrows: false, //boş satırları göstermez
     });
     fileReader.onerror = ((error) => {
         console.dir(error, { depth: null })

     });

     setexcData(jsonData);
}
```